# Cannot run Shiny web server until "download.file" was used in R session

Tags: r, windows, shiny, race-condition

I am currently developing a web app with the Shiny package for R. While this was working well the first days, I am currently stucked with a strange problem - although I found a workaround.

If I start the my script like I normally would, I receive strange errors (differing on operating system - I use Windows 10 and 7):

Permission / access denied

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6054
Fehler in shell.exec(url) : Zugriff auf 'http://127.0.0.1:6054' verweigert
Ruft auf: runApp -> <Anonymous> -> shell.exec
Ausführung angehalten
```

or

```
'localhost' not found
```

or

```
Warning: Error in : OpenSSL error in win32_load: could not load the shared library
```

or

```
ODBC connection failed
```

The actual code is working, because I already found a strange workaround for it: All these errors are fixed if I install a package as first action of a session (doesn't matter which or if it is already installed) or just run `available.packages`.

I analyzed the ["official" R source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/67d9243cabf48eb447e7ececc8f6849ac200e198/src/library/utils/R/packages.R) and tracked that down to the line (line 69) where the available packages are downloaded from a repo. I narrowed it some more, and it is also working for *any other* URL.

So this is my current workaround (executed before libraries are loaded):

```
download.file(url = "http://www.google.com", destfile = "h:/test")
```

In my opinion **this just makes no sense**!

I checked R session dump before and after, the Windows event log, disabled the firewall - and many things more. So my question what be what could be an explanation for this??

EDIT:
[Reported issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1739)

Comment: It's not clear how R packaging system is causing problems here. My initial thought is, something's up with shiny...

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with `utils::browseURL("http://www.google.com")` instead of running a Shiny app? Have you recently upgraded to R 3.4.0, and if so, what does `.libPaths()` return?

Comment: No, has to be download.file. Neither libPaths nor sessionInfo is changing by doing so (I installed R "cleanly" at least 10 times). Interesting: at my office I had to pick another URL instead of google, perhaps it is cached and it is some kind of race condition, needing some ms more?

Comment: I played around with sleep, but that does not make a difference - using R 3.4.0 and R 3.4.0 patched